# Determining the HTTP status code to return for a request

Tags: scala, comparative-review, http

I have a piece of code that I would like to refactor but can't figure how to do it. This is a method from a Play controller where I have to verify many precondition and respond different status for each case :

1. *resource* should exist or **404**
2. *revision* should match the `If-Match` value or **412**
3. *payload* should be valid or **422**

The first attempt looks like below. How do you implement such a suite of verifications?

```
service.find(key).map { resource => 
  request.headers.get("If-Match").map { expected =>
    if ( resource.revision == expected ) {
      val payload = request.body.validate[Model]
      payload match {
        case JsSuccess(model, _) =>
          Ok()
        case JsError(errors) => 
          UnprocessableEntity()
      }
    } else {
      PreconditionFailed()
    }
  }
} getOrElse {
  NotFound()
}
```

My best attempt is now to have one method who create a triplet of `Option[Resource], String, JsResult[Model]` and use pattern matching for each case :

```
 condition match {
   case (None, _, _) =>
     NotFound()
   case (Some(resource), expected, _) if ( resource.revision!=expected ) =>
     PreconditionFailed()
   case (_, _, JsError(errors)) =>
     UnprocessableEntity()
   case (Some(resource), _, JsSuccess(model, _)) =>
     Ok()
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You should learn more about partial functions. Everything you need to know is written in the [documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/PartialFunction.html).

It is a structure that allows you to do a basic check on something and if it succeed, it does something. It is composed of two methods :

- `apply(v1: A): B`
- `isDefinedAt(x: A): Boolean`

It applies the `apply` method on your input parameter only if the `isDefinedAt` method returned `true` when called with your input parameter.

The great thing about partial functions is that you can chain them easily with the `andThen`, `compose` and `applyOrElse` operators. Also, they can be written very easily by using the `case` syntax :

```
val divideByTwo: PartialFunction[Int, Int] = { case d: Int if d%2 == 0 => d/2 }
```

But there is another way to write it :

```
val divideByTwo = new PartialFunction[Int, Int] {
  def apply(d: Int) = d / 2
  def isDefinedAt(d: Int) = (d%2 == 0)
}
```

Here is a [great article](http://blog.bruchez.name/2011/10/scala-partial-functions-without-phd.html) about it.